# Website goes slow down after importing long database

Tags: wp-query, database, performance

I am working on a site which have 2 lakhs post and 15 categories. I have home page with 3 post of each category on home page. And after that its goes down while run home page and shows page not found. Can you give me any solution about to run fast my website's home page.
I am using

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => DESC, 'category' => 3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Imho are here too many answers possible. You do not tell  relevant extra information as in the amount of queries/memory/kind of server(shared/dedicated) it uses and so on. I can imagine that your db says.. sorry.. timeout, too many queries at once, not enough memory and so on because you talk about a db with a huge amount of posts(assuming it has also a certain amount of images). 200k posts are imho a lot and normaly needs a good configured server with enough cpu power/enough memory and more. It also depends on used "tools".(lazy load, Caching progs and so on) So a little more info maybe?

Comment: Btw, did the import go flawless, did you run an optimize db job, what does the log tell(debug.log/server error logfiles).

Comment: Hi, I am using shared server. And yes its says time out because of taking lot time. So i need to optimize db or any other solution